# Why do you need to use const in following operator overloading?

Tags: c++

This is a code for adding 3 objects of class Integer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Integer
{
    int value;
    public:
    Integer(int i) 
    { 
        value = i; 
    };
    int getValue() 
    { 
        return value; 
    }
    friend Integer operator+(const Integer & a,const Integer & b)
    {
        Integer i(a.value+b.value);
        return i;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Integer a(1), b(2), c(3);
    Integer d = a + b + c; //****HERE****
    cout << d.getValue() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why const is added to parameters in this case. If I remove const, during compilation I get invalid operands to binary operation error. 
Adding to this question:
 When I only add a and b without const, output is 3 without any errors. However, adding 3    a+b+c     objects, I get an error. Why is that?

Comment: If you don't use `const` then it allows for the possibility of a binary operator to modify an operand, which is not allowed.

Comment: As a style note, you're also not changing a or b;  nor would you ever want to in that operator - so using const will also protect you from doing silly things by mistake in that function...

Comment: @EliSadoff A binary operator is *allowed* to modify an operand. Whether it *should* do it is a separate question.

Comment: @EliSadoff: This analysis is incorrect. See the answers from Xirema and Barry, that I've just upvoted.

Comment: @Bathsheba I realized as such. I apparently misunderstood the concept myself.

Comment: As a service to future readers and people searching for a problem on Google, it is always a good idea to copy & paste the exact error into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say hypothetically we had written this function:

```
friend Integer operator+(Integer& a, Integer& b);
```

Stylistically, this isn't great because `operator+` shouldn't be modifying its arguments. But let's say we don't care about that. Now, what happens when we try to do this:

```
Integer d = a + b + c;
```

This is grouped as `(a+b)+c`. The `a+b` subexpression will find our `operator+()`, which is a viable function because `a` and `b` are non-`const` lvalues of type `Integer`, and the result of that expression is an rvalue of type `Integer`.

The subsequent expression is `{some rvalue Integer} + c`. *That* expression we won't be able to find a viable function for. While `c` can bind to `Integer&`, the first argument cannot - you can't bind an rvalue to a non-`const` lvalue reference. So you'd have to write something like:

```
Integer tmp = a + b; // OK
Integer d = tmp + c; // also OK
```

but now we're introducing this extra name into our scope and an extra statement into our code just to get around the unviability of our function signature.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to bind a Temporary to a [non-const-]reference, which isn't allowed in C++.

In the code `Integer d = a + b + c;`, `a + b` is evaluated first, and creates a new temporary object which then gets evaluated against c. So the code then becomes `Integer d = t<a+b> + c;`. Because the first object is now a temporary, only three function signatures will accept it as a parameter: `const Integer &`, `Integer`, and `Integer &&`. The second is not advised because it will create a copy of the object (though, sometimes that's what you want!), and the latter isn't advised because it will refuse to accept persistent objects. The first option, then, is best, because it will accept any `Integer` object regardless of whether it's expiring or not.

Recommended Reading: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) It's very verbose, and will probably require several passes before you "get" it, but it's extremely valuable knowledge for any C++ programmer.